# import and export may only appear at the top level - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, console, jsx

Good day Everyone,
I'm trying to run a query that increases a number whenever a button is clicked. I'm using a course from udemy is kinda old and our setup/installation is different. Please look at my code down below.

```
let count = 0;
const addOne = () => {
  count++;
  rendertheCounterApp();
};

const minus =() => {
  console.log('Minus',);
}

const Reset = () => {
  console.log ('Reset');
};
  const rendertheCounterApp = () => {
    const App = () => {
      return (
        <div className='App'>
          <h1>Toggler {count} </h1>
          <button onClick ={addOne}> +1 </button>
          <button onClick={minus}>-1</button>
          <button onClick ={Reset}>Rest</button>
        </div>
      );
    };
    export default App;
  };
  rendertheCounterApp();
```

is there any way I can modify that code to make the number increase whenever I click on the button?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have state to store the count and you can increase or decrease the count without creating any special functions. Try something like:

```
       import React, { useState } from 'react';  
  
       const RenderTheCounterApp = () => {
         const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
        
         return (
           <div>
             <h1>count: {count}</h1>
             <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Add</button>
             <button onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}>Subtract</button>
             <button onClick={() => setCount(0)}>Reset</button>
           </div>
         );
        };
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll try it out and get back to you.

Comment: Hey buddy,
I just checked it out just now, and I got invalid Hooks Call.
Is there a way I can fix that?
Thanks buddy!

Comment: maybe you are not importing `useState`. You can update your question with the current solution.

Comment: I'm not importing useState, and I'm currently running it on codesandbox.io
I'm not sure what the error might be!